# How do I "save as pdf" mat-table in angular 6

Tags: angular6, export-to-pdf, angular-material-6

I have used angular-materialize theme. I am beginner for Angular framework.
But I don't find a right way to export table as pdf.

I have created demo sample from 
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview
this official site.

My requirement is select date and then allow user to print in pdf.
if anyone has an idea or example, It would be very helpful.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/xbprlqrqjyq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: 2 solutions: generate the pdf on the server side (preferred one), or generate a printable page with only your table (like your example) so that the user can print to file using its browser from the print menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HTML:

> Blockquote

```
  <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="print()">
   <mat-icon class="mat-24" aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">print</mat-icon>
Print
```

> Blockquote

## Javascript/typescript:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
print = () => {
  let doc = new jsPDF(); 
  doc.autoTable({
    head: [['Log','', 'Amount']],
    body: this.getLiveData() //returning [["log1", "$100"], ["log2", "$200"]]
  });
  doc.save('table.pdf')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This answer update might be too late , but still might be useful for someone.**

`mat-table-exporter` -  this npm package allows to download the mat-table in  various formats.

Package Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo

Sample code :

```
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('json')">Json</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('txt')">Txt</button>
```